# Calculate SQL values into new insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't have enough points to post images, but here is a link to my table screen shot: [My query screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMNS5.jpg)

I have a SQL Server table with sick and leave time taken by employees. Our code did not enter the Forward balance for 2016-08-01 (That has been fixed). I need to take the Forward balance from 2016-07-01 (19.32) and add the Earned from 2016-06-30 (6.66) and subtract all the taken between 2016-07-01 to 2016-07-31 (3, 6 and 1.5) and insert it into a new record similar to row 3 and 10 but the forward Balance should be 13.48.

How do I write a SQL statement to do that for all `EmployeeID`? I tried to use SUM but that didn't work out right.

```
Select Value 
From  EmployeeVacations 
Where Vacation_Kind = 'SL'
  and Vacation_Type = 'Forward' 
  and CreationDate = '2016-07-01' 
  and EmployeeId = 1775
```

Plus:

```
Select Value 
From  EmployeeVacations 
Where Vacation_Kind = 'SL' 
  and Vacation_Type = 'Earned' 
  and CreationDate = '2016-06-30' 
  and EmployeeId = 1775
```

Minus:

```
Select SUM(Value) as TotalTaken 
From  EmployeeVacations 
Where Vacation_Kind = 'SL' 
  and Vacation_Type = 'Taken' 
  and CreationDate >= '2016-07-01' 
  and CreationDate <= '2016-07-31' 
  and EmployeeId = 1775
```

and then take the value from these three and insert into a new record like

```
INSERT into EmployeeVacations ([EmployeeId], [Vacation_Kind], [Vacation_Type], [CreationDate], [Value]) 
VALUES (1775, 'SL', 'Forward', '2016-08-01', 13.48)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't reproduce your data so I couldn't test this, but I think you should go for an approach like this:

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeVacations ([EmployeeId], [Vacation_Kind], [Vacation_Type], [CreationDate], [Value])
SELECT EmployeeId, 'SL', 'Forward', '2016-08-01', SUM(Value)
FROM (
    Select EmployeeId, Value 
    From  EmployeeVacations 
    Where Vacation_Kind = 'SL'
    and Vacation_Type = 'Forward' 
    and CreationDate = '2016-07-01' 

    UNION ALL

    Select EmployeeId, Value 
    From  EmployeeVacations 
    Where Vacation_Kind = 'SL' 
    and Vacation_Type = 'Earned' 
    and CreationDate = '2016-06-30' 

    UNION ALL

    Select EmployeeId, -Value
    From  EmployeeVacations 
    Where Vacation_Kind = 'SL' 
    and Vacation_Type = 'Taken' 
    and CreationDate >= '2016-07-01' 
    and CreationDate <= '2016-07-31' 
) SubQ
GROUP BY EmployeeId
```

As you can see, I'm just using a subquery with all the info that you need and nothing else, and then I just group it by employee.

Of course, you should first run it without the `INSERT` line to make sure you are getting what you need.

Comment: Ah, Union All... That's new to me. I know enough SQL for most basic stuff, but I'll give this a try tomorrow at work. Thanks!

Comment: @RickCJ7 - Make sure you mark it as answer when it is working for you

Comment: The third select should give error. You can't use sum with other columns without using group by clause. It's an aggregate function. Either you can use it alone in the select statement i.e. without employeeId or use group by clause.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew That fixed it! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Try this query: It should give you the desired result. First check it for one employee like the 1775 in your example. Then test it for another employee. Then run without specifying any employee id (the current query doesn't specify any employee id. that part is commented out). It might require little modification but given your scenario I doubt that. If the results are fine then you can use it in the insert statement as shown in @Andrew answer.

```
SELECT
    EVF.EmployeeId
    ,'SL'
    ,'Forward'
    ,'2016-08-01'
    ,EVF.Value + EVE.EarnedLeave - EVT.TotalTaken AS Forward
FROM  EmployeeVacations EVF
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        EmployeeId
        ,Value AS EarnedLeave
    FROM EmployeeVacations
    WHERE
        Vacation_Kind = 'SL'
        AND Vacation_Type = 'Earned'
        AND CreationDate = '2016-06-30'
) EVE ON EVE.EmployeeID = EVF.EmployeeId
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        EmployeeId
        ,SUM(Value) AS TotalTaken
    FROM EmployeeVacations
    WHERE
        Vacation_Kind = 'SL'
        AND Vacation_Type = 'Taken'
        AND CreationDate >= '2016-07-01'
        AND CreationDate <= '2016-07-31'
    GROUP BY EmployeeId
) EVT ON EVT.EmployeeId = EVF.EmployeeId
WHERE
    Vacation_Kind = 'SL'
    AND Vacation_Type = 'Forward'
    AND CreationDate = '2016-07-01'
    --AND EmployeeId = 1775
```

Comment: Thanks The Shooter, your query was perfect for me to double-check the values of each employee before I ran the insert above.